# I don't want someone who is lonely. So what do I want?

Tags: word-request, antonyms

[Here are some antonyms for lonely](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/lonely):

```
populated
sociable
befriended
close
frequented
inhabited
loved
unlonely
```

Basically, by lonely I mean someone who feels lonely even in a crowd. Such people are usually depressed. They feel happy if *anyone* gives them some positive attention.

These people want a man in their life and they actively seek mates. Whereas a person who is comfortable in her own skin won't have to go on looking elsewhere for attention and love since they are enough for themselves.

What should I say when I have to say I want someone who is ....?

Comment: Generally girls would prefer independent and outgoing guys. If you'd like to imply happiness and also optimism [_cheerful_](http://www.yourdictionary.com/cheerful) would work best.

Comment: @Yuri what is the one word for what you have described?

Comment: I don't think there is one word which implies all these at the same time. If you'd like to describe a person who's not an utter [attention seeker](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention_seeking), i suggest independent. If you'd like to describe a guy who's [the life of the party](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/life-and-soul-of-the-party), I'd suggest cheerful. However I can say if a person is cheerful, (s)he's normally outgoing too so I'd suggest cheerful.

Comment: I think you want someone who's happy (or cheerful, as Yuri has suggested). It's not the "loneliness" that bothers you, it's the fact that "such people are usually depressed" itself that bothers you. And usually, we would say, "I want someone who's happy with himself, comfortable with himself, confident in who he is, etc." These sorts of things.

Comment: Meanwhile, there is an argument for just including the description that you used above verbatim (unless there's a character limit). If this is your ideal person, why not be as specific as possible? There are both arguments for and against being specific in goals.

Comment: "A person who is able to interact with others may still be lonely by heart"- from your comment to @Peter's answer. With this in mind, whatever that may be suggested to you won't fit your request which, with "I want someone who is..." reads like a riddle, "guess what I have in mind". I wonder why nobody close voted the question yet as being too obscure.

Comment: Voting to close because the question shows no research effort: what are the definitions of those words, and how have the definitions proved inadequate, leading to OP's question.

Comment: @TRomano - Interesting; I upvoted this because I thought the question _did_ show research. At least antonyms were looked up and listed, and an explanation was given as to why those don't convey the sentiment being sought by the O.P.

Comment: @J.R.  Typing in a word at thesaurus.com is not research. Research would be looking up the definitions in one or more dictionaries, to see if the definition can narrow down the choice. If the definitions are not clear enough, then ask here, citing the ambiguity or lack of clarity in the definitions.

Comment: @TRomano - I don't see the need to define these eight words individually, just to show us all that words like _inhabited, populated,_ and _frequented_ don't quite mean "comfortable in one's own skin; won't have to look elsewhere for attention and love since they are enough for themselves." Perhaps a lookup of _unlonely_ might be in order, but, insofar as word requests go, this is as researched as many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to capture everything you want to say with a single word, but here is one suggestion:

> [**self-confident**](http://www.wordnik.com/words/self-confident) (*adj.*) showing poise and confidence in your own worth

You might be able to pinpoint what you're trying to say even more closely by pairing that with another adjective:

> **[affable](http://www.wordnik.com/words/affable)** (*adj.*) easy and pleasant to speak to; approachable, courteous, sociable; receiving others kindly and conversing with them in a free and friendly manner.

I think one who is seeking an "unlonely" person is looking for someone who is both *self-confident* and *affable*.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I read your added description

> ...won't have to go on looking elsewhere for attention and love since they are enough for themselves

I'd suggest *a person who has a strong sense of [self-esteem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-esteem)*. Self-esteem is what the world desperately needs since many problems starts when people don't see themselves as worthy e.i. they don't love themselves.

However, I find it rather hard to put this psychological concept in an adjective, [self-sufficient](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/self-sufficient) which means emotionally independent  and [self respectful](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-respectful) which basically means having self-esteem could be the candidates.

Again as previously I mentioned in my comment, if you mean a person who's happy and you can have fun with *cheerful* is a good choice of word.

Answer (score 0):

In dating speak, it's

> sociable

In corporate speak, it's

> a people person

It's basically a person who is comfortable interacting with people and possibly crowds. Not necessarily an *extrovert*, but definitely not an *introvert*.

Comment: But why? A person who is able to interact with others may still be lonely by heart. In fact I know such a person. You mean to say that a person who interacts with others won't be lonely?

Comment: The feeling of loneliness can occur for anyone in almost any circumstance.  Lovers after being intimate may feel "alone", If you could define what you mean by "loneliness" it may make the question clearer, otherwise your question may appear to be "opinion based".

Comment: I have added some more description.